# How do I log my user out using mvc's individual account authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

In my account controller the logout method is:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    return RedirectToAction("UserLogin", "Account");
}
```

Additionally on the LoginPartial, a javascript function is used to assist in logging the user out when he clicks the logoff link at the top of the page when he is logged in:

```
 <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
```

I am trying to duplicate this within my controller to prevent text from being input into the querystring. If text is input, I want to log the user out.

```
string newNum = Request.Params["unum"];
int unum = 0;
bool res = int.TryParse(newNum, out unum);
if(res == false)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Session.Abandon();
    return RedirectToAction("UserLogin","Account");
}
```

The page redirects and user is still logged in. How is this done?

Comment: ASP.Net Identity and FormsAuthentication are totally two different systems.

Comment: So presumably you just want to add AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie) where you now have FormsAuthentication.SignOut() ?

Comment: @Win I was following tutorials here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll When I tried that, I got an error stating that AuthenticationManager had no method called SignOut